# TFS Mac agent not running as a service

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am using TFS 2018. I have a Mac agent. Its configured success and run well. Now i want to run this agent as a service in Mac machine. To do it we need to run ./svc.sh file. But I run ./svc.sh file. agent is not running in TFS, it shows offline.

Comment: What's the behavior if run `./svc.sh stop`?

Comment: its working. no erors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart Mac machine its worked for me.